# Is it possible to install WordPress Multisite on a subdomain with subdirectories?

Tags: permalinks, multisite, installation, subdomains

This is something I have never tried so far. On a webspace I want to have a subdirectory like this:

> blognetwork.example.com

Then I want to run Multisite with subdirectories like this:

```
blognetwork.example.com/blog/
blognetwork.example.com/site1/
blognetwork.example.com/site2/
```

Is this possible or will it lead to unpredictable issues? Someone ever tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

All you need to do is to install your WordPress on the subdomain, turn the Multisite on and set it to use subdirectories for sites.

Make sure the following is set in multisite constants:

```
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it by putting this `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);` in `config.php` file.

[For mere please follow this link](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/)